# how Identification and send new data in program at sql

Tags: c#, winforms, sql-server-2008

I wrote a program with `C#`, `Sql-Server-2008`, `.Net 4` and installed on two systems with spatial distance.

I want send new information (data in `sql`) from a `program1` to `program2`.
How can Detect we give any new information (data in `sql`) in `program1` and send there are to `sql` in `program2`?

Comment: I think better solution if you will have some common program (server layer) maybe web service, which can get sql queries and save or return data.

Comment: @Sergey Gazaryan: This is a client program and am looking for a more simple way.

Comment: Establishing some sort of communication between clients to synchronize data is going to be a lot more complicated than just using one sql server and having all the clients check it for new data.  You don't have to pull down data to see if it's changed, you can pull down checksums and compare them to a stored value to see if you need get the full data.

Comment: Please give me the training materials and resources for the job

Comment: Ok @AhmadKarimi ,  I not recommend but you can do by adding modifyDate column in your tables and have another table (lastProgramWhichModifiedData, modifiedDate) and periodically your programs can check if some data  modified and get it. This is wrong solution of course. I think you need have another part in your system which can send data to your program

Comment: @SergeyGazaryan : thx. please help me for another part in my system which can send data to my program